# Meaning of the differential form of Gauss's theorem and Poisson's equation

Tags: electrostatics, differential-geometry, electric-fields, potential, gauss-law

The differential form of Gauss's theorem is that the divergence of the electric field is proportional to the charge density of the region being considered (crudely speaking).

My question is, how is the charge density defined? That is, does the theorem assume a uniform charge density or is it just the charge enclosed divided by the volume being considered?

How is Poisson's equation used then? Poisson's equation suggests that the Laplacian of the potential at a point inside a region that has some charge density is proportional to the enclosed charge density. However, I don't understand that clearly because it appears as if the Laplacian would change if the same point was assumed to be in a region enclosing a different set of charges which does not make sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're concerned about the difference between the charge density within a non-zero volume (i.e. $Q/V$ for some $V \neq 0$) and the charge density at a single point (with zero volume).  But you can view one as the limit of the other.  For example, if we consider some point $\vec{r}$ in space, and we define $Q(R)$ to be the amount of charge inside a sphere of radius $R$ centered at $\vec{r}$, then the charge density $\rho$ at $\vec{r}$ will be equal to
$$
\rho(\vec{r}) = \lim_{R \to 0} \frac{Q(R)}{\frac{4}{3} \pi R^3}.
$$
Most of the continuous charge distributions we consider in electrodynamics are "well-behaved" enough that it doesn't matter how we take this limit (i.e., I could have used little cubes or ellipsoids instead of spheres).  This means that in general, we can think of $\rho(\vec{r})$ as that function for which the amount of charge $\Delta Q$ in any "small" volume $\Delta V$ including $\vec{r}$ is
$$
\Delta Q \approx \rho( \vec{r}) \Delta V,
$$
where the level of agreement between the two sides gets better the smaller you make $\Delta V$.

In other words, once you "zoom in" enough on the charge distribution at any point, it looks basically uniform near that point.  You should really think of $\rho$ as then telling you the charge density in "small" volumes near that point;  since the charge density is "basically uniform" on a small scale, the distinction you're concerned about (uniform density vs. charge in a particular volume) doesn't matter.

The $\rho(\vec{r})$ that appears in Gauss's Law and Poisson's Equation then corresponds to the charge density at that particular point.  For example, in Poisson's equation,
$$
\nabla^2 V = - \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0},
$$
we mean that the Laplacian of $V$ at the point $\vec{r}$ is equal to $-1/\epsilon_0$ times the charge density at the point $\vec{r}$.

Comment: Although that's clear, it does not answer my question. What I am asking is, what "charge density" do I pick when I am evaluating the Poisson's equation at a point in a region?

Comment: @PradyothShandilya: You use the charge density at that point.  I'll see if I can edit my answer to make this clearer.

Comment: Wait, so you're saying that the Poisson's equation is evaluated at a point based on the "charge density" at that point? So the Laplacian of the potential at that point does not matter how charges are distributed relatively far from that point?

Comment: @PradyothShandilya:  That's correct.  The Laplacian of the potential at a particular point is entirely determined by the charge density at that point.

Answer (score 0):

First The integral form of Gauss's Law given by,

For any closed surface 
$$\oint_S \mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{a}=\frac{Q_{enc}}{\epsilon_0}$$
Here it doesn't matter where the charge is located in closed volume and thus distribution can be anything ,Given a charge you can find the Flux.
While in differential form $$\nabla\cdot \mathbf{E}=\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$$
$$Q_{enc}=\int_V \rho d\tau$$
Here charge distribution does matter and thus it does matter How the charge distributed over a volume.Given the charge distribution you can find the divergence at some point in space and for static case One has $\nabla \times \mathbf{E}=0$ and Thus by Helmholtz theorem one can  uniquely define the Electric field. So First form is less specific and thus only talk about flux but second one More specific thus give the electric field.

Second:Poisson Equation is given by $$\nabla ^2V=-\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}$$
and that says if you give me charge distribution ,I can tell potential at any point so Potential as function of space coordinates or  vice-versa.
So here also charge distribution does matter if you change charge distribution Potential and thus electric field does change.